# HTML5 Application Cache in IE8-9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, application-cache

HTML5 Application Cache isn't supported by IE8 and IE9.

What would happened with website which uses HTML5 Application Cache when opened in IE8 for example? Will it be loaded as usual or throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Cache works by adding `manifest` attribute to the `<html>` element. Browsers simply ignore attributes which they don't understand, so IE 8 or 9 would behave as if this attribute wasn't there.

However, if you try to access Application Cache through JavaScript by using the `applicaitonCache` property of `window`, your code may throw an error. For example this code:

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', onUpdateReady);
```

would throw error, something like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Note that Application Cache is now deprecated and you should use Service Workers instead.

Comment: service-worker isn't fully supported by major browsers yet. Anyway, thanks for you comment, it gave me the info I was looking for.